# consul v1.0.0 service can't deregister

Tags: consul

I use consul for service recovery, after register a service named 'ngx' whith checks for port 8888, it works well.

But when i want to deregister this service , it's not work

[image]

when the first time i put deregister to consul ,  there is no service ngx, but for a while (about half a minute) i check again, the service comeback again.....

i read the doc on consul.io , but can't find any other method to do.

Answer (score 0):

problem is not with consul, docker conatiner nginx is getting redeployed again.
check docker ps after u do deregister,
how you are registering service using deregister service? or rest call.